# Which Python version is installed in another conda env

Tags: python, conda

How can I find out which Python version is installed in a `conda` environment where I know the name, but do not want to activate that environment?

Background: I have chosen the lazy way to get `python3.6` on my `Ubuntu 14.04` machine and installed `conda`. But I would like to add certain directories to my `PYTHONPATH` depending on whether the environment has `python2.x` or `python3.x` and I plan to do this by wrapping `conda`'s `activate` like so:

```
PYMAJOR=$(a_miracle_occurs $CONDAENV)
BASHRC=$(cat <<EOF
source ~/.bashrc
source activate $CONDAENV
export PATH=...
export PYTHONPATH=".../modules$PYMAJOR"
"
EOF
)
bash --rcfile <(echo "${BASHRC}")
```

I have no compatibility issues with subversions of `python` and I do not want to `setup.py develop` the modules in the `PYTHONPATH`-to-be because there are still too many changes, also on structural level.

Remark: I am aware of `conda list -n ENVNAME` but this would involve parsing human readable output and I would feel better off to have something retrieving the info in machine readable form.

Answer (score 20):

Here is a one-liner that will print the environments and the associated python versions:

```
conda env list | grep -v "^$\|#" |awk '{print $1;}'|xargs -I{} -d "\n" sh -c 'printf "Env: {}\t"; conda list -n {} |grep "^python\s";'
```

Here is a sample output:

```
Env: base   python                    2.7.14              h1571d57_29  
Env: python37   python                    3.7.0                hc3d631a_0
```

Rationale: Get the list of environments with `conda env list`, exclude empty lines and #, parse, print the environment packages with `conda list -n <env>` and grep for python.

You are welcome to adapt the formatting to your liking.

Comment: Hi. And how would I get python versions of the various conda environments on Windows? Thank you.

Comment: With formatted output @eiomage one liner would be: 
 
`conda env list | grep -v "^$\|#" | awk '{print $1;}' | xargs -I{} -d "\n" sh -c  'printf %-20s "{}"; conda list -n {} | grep "^python\s"'`.

Comment: On OSX (which has an older version of xargs) the above will fail. This command works: `conda env list | grep -v "^$\|#" |awk '{print $1;}'|xargs -I{} -n 1 sh -c 'printf "Env: {}\t"; conda list -n {} |grep "^python\s";'`

Comment: @xavriley I gather you just removed `-d '\n'`?

Answer (score 2):

I am not at all familiar with anaconda and everything that follows is a wild guess. If anaconda uses virtualenv internally, the virtualenv should be installed into some directory (maybe something like `$ANACONDA_HOME/envs/$CONDAENV`?).

If that's the case, then the Python version should be retrievable by simply running `$ANACONDA_HOME/envs/$CONDAENV/bin/python --version`.

**EDIT** to address OPs comment:

To only return the version string try:

```
$ANACONDA_HOME/envs/$CONDAENV/bin/python -c 'import platform; print(platform.python_version())'
>>> 3.6.0
```

Comment: `$ ~/miniconda2/envs/$CONDAENV/bin/python --version` prints `Python 3.6.1 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.` which would still require parsing, but I can add a mini inline script with `-c '...'` which `stdout.write`s the `sys.version_info.major`. Great guess :)

Comment: for conda 4.7.12, `$ ANACONDA_HOME/bin/python --version` works

Answer (score 2):

With referencing [elomage's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52408794/8886408), I have written a powershell command with the same behaviour.

```
conda env list | Select-String -Pattern  "^$|#" -NotMatch | ForEach-Object{($_ -split "\s+")[0]} | %{ "Env: {0}`t{1}" -f $_, (conda list -n $_ | Select-String -Pattern "^python\s") }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt at a one-liner:

```bash
cenvs=$(conda env list | grep -ve '^#'); paste <(echo "$cenvs" | awk '{printf "%-15s\n", $1}') <(echo "$cenvs" | awk '
{print $2}' | xargs -I {} sh -c '{}/bin/python --version')
```

unlike @elomage's answer, this one only calls `conda list` once, instead of once per environment, which speeds up things tremendously.

It works by taking the path to each environment printed by `conda env list` and appending `bin/python` and executing that python binary with the `--version` flag.

It's a bit gnarly, but gets the job done fast.